# Add extra top .offset()

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I was wondering how to add extra 'top' .offset() to this div;

## mapstick

I think its something to do startPosition?? I thought I could get away with changing it in CSS but this just broke the function of the div unsticking at a certain height.

I tried in the CSS to make the top px '!important' on the div. This is what broke the if/else statement as it messed up what the actual top of the div and the script didn't realise this it looks like.

```
var navWrap = $('#navWrap'),
    nav = $('#mapstick'),
    startPosition = navWrap.offset().top,
    stopPosition = $('#stopHere').offset().top - nav.outerHeight();

$(document).scroll(function () {
    //stick nav to top of page
    var y = $(this).scrollTop()

    if (y > startPosition) {
        nav.addClass('sticky');
        if (y > stopPosition) {
            nav.css('top', stopPosition - y);
        } else {
            nav.css('top', 0);
        }
    } else {
        nav.removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

I just need an extra 70px on the top of the div so it can be fully visible.

I have also looked at using this;

```
.offset({ top: 70 });
```

I think I used this wrong as this just messed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can just amend another class to a child div to have the effect that I am wanting. So I have just added an extra 'addClass' to the if statement and it seems to have done the trick.

This is the script that I have now;

```
var navWrap = $('#navWrap'),
    nav = $('#mapstick'),
    maptop = $('#map')
    startPosition = navWrap.offset().top  ,
    stopPosition = $('#stopHere').offset().top   - nav.outerHeight();

$(document).scroll(function () {
    //stick nav to top of page
    var y = $(this).scrollTop()

    if (y > startPosition) {
        nav.addClass('sticky'),
        maptop.addClass('maptop');
        if (y > stopPosition) {
            nav.css('top', stopPosition - y);
        } else {
            nav.css('top', 0);
        }
    } else {
        nav.removeClass('sticky'),
        maptop.addClass('maptop');
    }
});
```

I have added in the 'maptop' to the if statement which is working. I don't know if this is the best way to do it but it is working and I am fine with that lol